# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

Despite the fact that I can make this bootstrap-multiselect work in independent file, I'm not able to see the dropdown list once I click on caret, even if I included it in portal files.

I have already used bootstrap-datepicker, datetimepicker, chosen, and backbone.js

This is the line which is supposed to do the trick

```
$('.insightList').multiselect({
            selectAllText: true
});
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can be the cause for not adding class 'open' for 'btn-group'?

![On click also there is only btn-group class for div whether it should add open class][1]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your problem??

Answer (score 2):

I've just created a jsbin to solve your problem [Working demo](http://jsbin.com/qugefi/1/edit?html,css,output).

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example by @Bneiluj</title>
</head>
<body>

  <select id="insightList" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
      <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
      <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
      <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
      <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

<script id="example">
$('#insightList').multiselect({
  enableClickableOptGroups: true
});
</script>
```

Please, let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Occurrence of the

- Bootstrap.js
- Bootstrap-select.js
- Bootstrap-multiselect.js

if one of them exist more then 1 times then the dropdown will not displayed

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I had 2 bootstrap.min.js added and it was causing the multiselect to not expand

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTML structure for the dropdown is as follows:

```
<select id="example-selectAllText" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
 <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
 <option value="4">Option 4</option>
 <option value="5">Option 5</option>
 <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected" aria-expanded="false"><span class="multiselect-selected-text">None selected</span> <b class="caret"></b></button><ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"><li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all"><a tabindex="0" class="multiselect-all"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all"> Check all!</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1"> Option 1</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2"> Option 2</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3"> Option 3</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="4"> Option 4</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="5"> Option 5</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="6"> Option 6</label></a></li></ul></div>

$('#example-selectAllText').multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  selectAllText: 'Check all!'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple multi select am trying to build with the same bootstrap multiselect I have loaded all the necessary jquery and css but still it shows a select box displaying all the options it has not as proposed in above solution.

```
<select id="multi-select" name="field" multiple="multiple" >
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
 <!-- initialize multiselect -->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mult-select').multiselect();
    });
</script><!-- //ends-->
```